Multiple copies of Realtek audio codec in device manager causes low sound
In
c:\windows\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository
I have the following folders:
realtekhsa.inf_amd64_d715...
realtekintapo.inf_amd64_8a55...
realtekservice.inf_amd64_c607...
realtekservice.inf_amd64_e4e9...
realtekusbapo.inf_amd64_9359...
In device manager under sounds I have 3 copies of:
realtek soundwire hw audio codec device driver
This causes very low sound until I delete at least one of the codecs. I'v tried to uninstall and remove files from device manager but they keep coming back.
How do I completely remove the drivers? Can I unistall from device manager and just delete the folders?
In control panel I have realtek usb and realtek audio installed too.
I also did a reinstall of the OS and still got 3 copies of Realtek audio codec in device manager
I would then reinstall the device driver from a download from dell.
If this is not the right forum to post please indicate where I should post. Thanks
